# Initialized values for redux form fields

Tags: redux-form

I am using `this.props.initialize(initData)` to initialize the react form field values. inittdata contains the data in below format. I have also imported initialize from redux form. Below is the compilation error I am getting.

```
handleInitialize() {
        const initData = {
          "firstName": this.state.firstName,
          "lastName": this.state.lastName

};
```

Error:

> [ts] Property 'initialize' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> & Readonly<{}>'

Comment: Please share more of your form/component code if you can

Comment: this is my form field -                                                                  
        render() {
  const form = (
   <Form>
    <Field name="email"   component={this.renderInput}  validate={[email, required]} />
    <Field
     name="password"
     component={this.renderInput}
     
    />
   </Form>
  );
  
  return <Login loginForm={form} onLogin={() => this.login()} toggleSwitch={(value) => this.toggleRememberMe(value)}
   navigation={this.props.navigation} switchValue={this.state.rememberMeValue} touchIdHandler={() => this.touchIdHandler()} />;
 }

Comment: this is how i am initializing values-componentDidMount(){

  this.handleInitialize();
 }

 handleInitialize() {
  const initData = {
    "firstName": this.state.firstName,
    "lastName": this.state.lastName,
  };
 
  this.props.initialize({email:"pawan"});
   }

Comment: Initialization looks correct but I think you should check your render method, what is <Login> component for instance? Have you checked this doc? https://redux-form.com/7.3.0/examples/initializefromstate/